# How to use router.replace inside the client side of your app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, next-router

I'm trying to use Next.js router to redirect unauthorized users from accessing certain pages that are wrapped inside the `AdminLayout` component, but I got this error.

> Error: No router instance found. You should only use "next/router"
>   inside the client side of your app.

[image: No router instance found]

```
// Other imports
import Router from "next/router";

class AdminLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.props;

    if (currentUser === undefined) {
      console.log(currentUser);
      return null;
    }

    if (currentUser == null) {
      console.log(currentUser);
      //this is how I tried to redirect
      Router.replace("/admin/login");
    }
    return (
      // Other irrelevant code
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  currentUser: state.user.currentUser,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AdminLayout);
```

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`render` method is executed in the server as well, therefore you get the exception.

Usually it is a **bad practice** to put **side effect** (such as redirects) in the `render` method.

You should put it inside `componentDidMount` which runs only on the client side.

```js
// Other imports
import Router from "next/router";

class AdminLayout extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const {currentUser} = this.props;

    if (currentUser === undefined) {
      console.log(currentUser);
      return null;
    }

    if (currentUser == null) {
      console.log(currentUser);
      //this is how I tried to redirect
      Router.replace('/admin/login');
    }
  }
  render() {
    const {currentUser} = this.props;

    if (currentUser === undefined) {
      console.log(currentUser);
      return null;
    }
    return (
      // Other irrelevant code
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  currentUser: state.user.currentUser,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AdminLayout);
```

If you want to redirect on in the server side you will need to use `getInitialProps` / `getServerProps` which runs on **the server**, these methods on the server side it gets the server `request` & `response` which enables you to redirect from the server.

```
class AdminLayout extends React.Component {
   static getInitialProps ({ res }) {
      if(someCondition) {
        res.redirect('/your-path');
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the redirect happen before the page renders?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: But doesn't getInitialProps() only work for pages and not for components? (AdminLayout is a component, and getInitialProps does not run here)

Comment: Correct, you can't redirect to other page from within a component. either client side redirection via componentDidMount or server side at the page level.

Comment: So any suggestions?

Comment: Make the redirection server side in the page level

Answer (score 4):

If anyone's facing the same error but a different situation, make sure you're using next router correctly.

my vscode extensions imported it like

`import router from 'next/router`

When it should be

`import {useRouter} from 'next/router'`

and then use it later like

`const router = useRouter()`

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this line before call the router.push("/"):

```
if (typeof window === "undefined") return null;
```

This will prevent your router from push when the clients still's rendering

Answer (score 0):

if you're using it inside a function you might've got the same error as I did,

Don't do it like this:

```
const router = useRouter() //wrong
Checkout.then(res => {
router...(URL)
})
```

Instead, do it like this:

```
Checkout.then(res => {
const router = useRouter() //correct
router...(URL)
})
```